# How to Open a page from one frame in another

Tags: asp.net, frame

I am using 4 frames in aspx page.The top frame is the banner frame,the menu frame,the content frame and the footer frame.

The menu frame loads the Menu.aspx page.This page contains the menu control.I have added some items in the menu.

What i want is when i click the menu item which is in the menu frame,i want the page to be loaded in the content frame.

How can i do it?

This is the default.aspx page which uses 4 frames

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>

</head>
<frameset rows="20%,80%,20%" frameborder="0">
<frame name="banner" src="a.htm"></frame>
    <frameset cols="20%,80%">
        <frame name="menu" src="Menu.aspx"></frame>
        <frame name="content" src="d.htm"></frame>
    </frameset>
<frame name="footer" src="b.htm"></frame>
```

This is the menu.aspx page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFBD6" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" 
    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="15px" ForeColor="#990000" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Height="300px">
        <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66"  />
        <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" />
        <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
        <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6"  />
        <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
        <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="10px" Font-Size="15px" />
        <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Home.aspx" Value="Home.aspx" NavigateUrl="~/Home.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Administration" Value="Administration" NavigateUrl="~/Administration.aspx">
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Add User" Value="Add User" NavigateUrl="~/AddUser.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Add Organization" Value="Add Organization" NavigateUrl="~/AddOrganization.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Add Program" Value="Add Program" NavigateUrl="~/AddProgram.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Add Activity" Value="Add Activity" NavigateUrl="~/AddActivity.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Search" Value="Search" NavigateUrl="~/Search.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Utilities" Value="Utilities" NavigateUrl="~/Utilities.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact Us" Value="Contact Us" NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you using frames? I see no merit to using frames in your case in the first place.

Comment: what can i go for instead of frames to avoid reloading of the entire page?

Comment: Use [UpdatePanels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to refresh only a part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very weired and inefficient way for making a website. Never implement this on any production server.

1 step - encapsulate all your iframes in seperate update panel.

2 step - add a timer control in all your updatepanel with the minimum refresh rate you are comformable with.

3 step. your logic will be smthing like this, when ever link is clicked from menu iframe set a session variable with required parameter like session["togo"] = "blabla.aspx"

4 step in timer tick event check for session if found reload the iframe to value specified.
set the session["togo"] to null.